# Chat Application using socket not working over Internet in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently developing chat application working over Internet.currently my application working fine over LAN but not working over Internet.I have also used port forwarding.I have done setting in modem and forward the port to private IP address but still it's not working.I got the error that "server isn't found".Please suggest me what I have to do and tell,Am I done the correct setting in modem or not??

Below is my server code...

```
Server.java

import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Server implements ChatConstants
{
  private static Vector list;
  private ServerSocket ssocket ;
  private Service service;
  private static Socket socket;
  private boolean done=false;
  private static Hashtable userTable = new Hashtable();
  private static Hashtable _userList = new Hashtable();
  private static Hashtable _conflist = new Hashtable();


public Server() throws UnknownHostException
{
    System.out.println("Initializing...");
    list=new Vector(BACKLOG);
    try {
        ssocket= new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT,BACKLOG);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Inside constructor"+e);
    }
    start();
}



public void start() throws UnknownHostException
{

    byte[] data;
    int header;
    Socket _socket = null;
    String hostname = null;
    System.out.println("Server successfully started at "
            +InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString()
            +" port "+SERVER_PORT);

     while(!done) {
                try 
                   {
                   _socket=ssocket.accept();

                    if(_socket != null) {
                     synchronized(list) {
                     list.addElement(_socket);
                }

                DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
                data = new byte[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
                dis.read(data);
                Message message = ((Message)ChatUtils.bytesToObject(data));
                System.out.println("Joined client "
                            +message._username+" at "+message._host+"...");
                synchronized(userTable) {
                    userTable.put(message._username,_socket);
                }
                addUser(message);
                sendUserList(message);
                writeToClients(message);
                service = new Service(_socket,hostname,message._user);
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Thread exception"+e);
            try {
                _socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR CLOSING SOCKET");
            }
        }
    }//END WHILE
}


private void addUser(Message message)
{
    synchronized(_userList) {
        _userList.put(message._user.toString(),message._user);
    }
}

public static void updateUser(User user)
{
    User myuser;
    synchronized(_userList) {
        _userList.put(user.toString(),user);
    }
}

public static synchronized void writeToClients(Message message)
{
    byte[] data;
    DataOutputStream dos;
        for(int count=0;count<list.size();count++) {
        try {
             dos=new 
                     DataOutputStream(((Socket)list.elementAt(count)).getOutputStream());
            data=ChatUtils.objectToBytes(message);
            dos.write(data,0,data.length);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Output exception");
        }
    }//END FOR
}

public static void writeToClient(Message message)
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] data;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    synchronized(userTable) {
        try {
            socket = (Socket)userTable.get(message._destination);
            dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            data=ChatUtils.objectToBytes(message);
            dos.write(data,0,data.length);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SEND EXCEPTION"+e);
        }
    }
}


public static void sendConferenceListToClient(Message message)
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] data;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    synchronized(userTable) {
        try {
            Message mymessage= new Message(CONFERENCE_LIST);
            Vector vector = (Vector)
                _conflist.get(message._destination);

            mymessage._username = message._username;
            mymessage._destination = message._destination;
            mymessage.userlist = vector;

            socket = (Socket)userTable.get(message._username);

            if(socket!=null) {
                dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                data=ChatUtils.objectToBytes(mymessage);
                dos.write(data,0,data.length);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("CONFERENCE LIST EXCEPTION"+e);
        }
    }
}


public static void writeToPublicChat(Message message)
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] data;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    synchronized(_conflist) {
        try {
            Vector svector = (Vector)_conflist.get(message._destination);
            for(int cnt=0;cnt<svector.size();cnt++) {
                synchronized(userTable) {
                    try {
                        socket = (Socket)userTable.get((svector.get(cnt).toString()));
                        if(socket!=null) {
                            dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            data=ChatUtils.objectToBytes(message);
                            dos.write(data,0,data.length);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("PUBLIC CHAT EXCEPTION"+e);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("PUBLIC EXCEPTION"+e);
        }
    }
}


public static void inviteToPublicChat(Vector svector,Message message)
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] data;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    synchronized(_conflist) {
        for(int cnt=0;cnt<svector.size();cnt++) {
            synchronized(userTable) {
                try {
                    socket = (Socket)userTable.get((svector.get(cnt).toString()));
                    if(socket != null) {
                        dos=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        data=ChatUtils.objectToBytes(message);
                        dos.write(data,0,data.length);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("PUBLIC INVITE EXCEPTION"+e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendUserList(Message message)
{
    int header=0;
    String destination;

    header=message._header;
    destination = message._destination;

    message._header = USERS_LIST;
    message._destination = message._username;

    message.userlist = new Vector(_userList.values());
    writeToClient(message);

    //Restore the headers
    message._destination = destination;
    message._header = header;

}

public static synchronized void removeUser(User user)
{
    try {
        Socket socket = (Socket)userTable.get(user.toString());
        list.removeElement(socket);
        _userList.remove(user.toString());
        userTable.remove(user.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR REMOVING SOCKET "+e);
    }
}


public static synchronized void processClientMessage(Message message)
{
    switch(message._header) {

        case CHANGE_STATUS:
            updateUser(message._user);
            writeToClients(message);
            break;

        case CLIENT_LOGOUT:
            removeUser(message._user);
            writeToClients(message);
            break;

        case CONFERENCE_CREATE:
            Vector myvector = new Vector();
            myvector.add(message._username);
            _conflist.put(message._user.toString(),myvector);
        case CONFERENCE_INVITE:
            inviteToPublicChat(message.userlist,message);
        break;

        case CONFERENCE_JOIN:
            Vector vector=null;
            vector = (Vector)
                _conflist.get(message._destination.toString());
            vector.add(message._username);
            _conflist.put(message._destination.toString(),vector);
            writeToPublicChat(message);
        break;

        case CONFERENCE_DENY:
            //_conflist.remove(message._user.toString(),message.userlist);
            writeToPublicChat(message);
        break;

        case CONFERENCE_LEAVE:
            Vector vectors =(Vector)
                _conflist.get(message._destination.toString());
            for(int count=0;count<vectors.size();count++) {
                if(message._username.equals((vectors.elementAt(count).toString())))
                    vectors.remove(count);
            }
            if(vectors.size() != 0)
                _conflist.put(message._user.toString(),vectors);
            else//IF THERE ARE NO MORE USERS
                _conflist.remove(message._user.toString());//DONE CONFERENCE
            writeToPublicChat(message);
        break;

        case PUBLIC_CHAT:
            writeToPublicChat(message);
        break;

        case CONFERENCE_LIST:
            sendConferenceListToClient(message);
        break;

        default:
            writeToClient(message);
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    Server chatserver=new Server();
}
  }


 //
 // Service: Service class for each clients connected to server.
 //


  class Service implements Runnable, ChatConstants
  {
private DataInputStream dis;
private Socket socket;
private boolean done=false;
private Thread thread;
private String hostname;
private User user;

public Service(Socket _socket,String _hostname,User user)
{
    try {
        this.socket = _socket;
        this.hostname=_hostname;
        this.user = user;
        dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        thread=new Thread(this,"SERVICE");
        thread.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("service constructor"+e);
    }
}

public void run()
{
    byte[] data;
    while(!done)
    {
        try {
            data = new byte[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
            dis.read(data);
            Message message = ((Message)ChatUtils.bytesToObject(data));
            Server.processClientMessage(message);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            done = true;
            Server.removeUser(user);
            Message message = new Message(CLIENT_LOGOUT);
            user.isOnline = OFFLINE;
            message._user = user;
            Server.writeToClients(message);
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR CLOSING SOCKET "+se);
            }
            //System.out.println("SERVICE THREAD EXCEPTION"+e);
        }
    }//END WHILE
}
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` to every catch.  As it is, I am not even sure which part of the code is causing the error you claim to see.

Comment: @Andrew :Thanks.I am not getting any error in the code but client code can't find the server when working over Internet because It's not in Network.Still I added e.printStackTrace().

Comment: @Krusnakant were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: What port are you using?  In my country the ISP's block all ports up to 1024 automatically for normal residential internet subscriptions.  They don't want us to provide internet services without a business subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I think the

```
ssocket= new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT,BACKLOG);
```

is making the issue. Use the version

```
ssocket= new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT,BACKLOG,LOCAL_INET_ADDRESS);
```

and bind server to some constant local IP. Now use the port forwarding  in the modem, to forward all requests to that local ip. Make sure that the firewall is not preventing you to use the port. Since firewall may allow a local networking but not to web.